# torch.cuda.is_available() return True inside PyCharm project, return False outside project in Terminal

Tags: python, pytorch, conda, torch

I have installed the latest pytorch with cuda support using `conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.7 -c pytorch -c nvidia` command.

When I run my project on Terminal anc activate conda environment, it returns `torch.cuda.is_available()` returns False and causes an error.

**Through Terminal**

```
(pytesseract) cvpr@cvprlab:/media/cvpr/CM_1/doctr-main/references/recognition$ python3
Python 3.9.16 (main, Jan 11 2023, 16:05:54) 
[GCC 11.2.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
>>> torch.zeros(1).cuda()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/cvpr/anaconda3/envs/pytesseract/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 247, in _lazy_init
    torch._C._cuda_init()
RuntimeError: No CUDA GPUs are available
```

But, when I run the project in PyCharm (in the same environment) it returns True. I add the screenshot below.

**PyCharm Project**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In PyCharm, the environment variables and path settings are managed by the IDE, and it automatically sets up the necessary configurations when you choose a Python interpreter for your project. When you select a conda environment as the interpreter, PyCharm will automatically load the environment variables from the activated environment, which includes the necessary paths for CUDA libraries if the environment was set up correctly.

On the other hand, when running your project through the terminal, the environment variables and path settings depend on your shell's configuration, such as your ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile files. If these configurations are not set up correctly, you could run into this issue.

Since you mentioned that the issue does not occur in PyCharm, it indicates that the environment variables and path settings are likely correct within the IDE. The problem seems to be with the terminal's environment, which might not have the correct paths or settings for your conda environment and CUDA libraries.

PyCharm might be using the full system path when running the terminal, whereas your regular terminal might be using the user path.

To verify this, you can check the environment variables in both the regular terminal and PyCharm's terminal:

```bash
echo $PATH
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

If there are differences in the paths, particularly regarding the CUDA-related paths, add the necessary paths to your ~/.bashrc (or equivalent) file:

```bash
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin:$PATH #May be different for you so check
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH #May be different for you so check
```

Then reload the terminal settings:

```bash
source ~/.bashrc
```

Then test torch.cuda.is_available() again in the terminal:

```py
python -c "import torch; print(torch.cuda.is_available())"
```

If it still returns as 'False' check your GPU drivers they may need a reinstallation and/or try reinstalling your conda environment

Comment: When I print echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH, it prints nothing on PyCharm Terminal. Why?